# How to follow up the result of postdoc committee?

Tags: postdocs

I have been accepted for postdoc position at university A. In the meanwhile, I applied for postdoc in university B, and I am waiting to hear from them.

I would like to write a follow-up email to my potential mentor at university B asking about the decision of their committee, because I need to finalize my decision about the job at university A. How can I express my situation in a polite email to university B?

Answer (score -1):

Just ask them if a decision is imminent as you are keen and motivated.

Trying to write some form of « I have an offer from X, should I take it? » may not help...